# Got warning with git branch and merge in xcode4

Tags: git, xcode4, branching-and-merging

I tried git integrated with xcode 4, but got problem on merge a branch back to master. When I develop new feature I create a new branch and add many new lib and files, the problem came when I want to merge this branch back to master. From my understanding I have to switch back to master and then merge feature-branch back to master, but when I tried to switch to master branch I got a lot of warning messages something like

> The file for the document that was at /Users/...../file_name.m has
>   disappeared. Do you want to re-save the document or close it?
>   (three options, re-save, cancel, save-as)

What should I do so I can merge with no warning, do I need to add .gitignore to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

- either XCode4 consider the opened file problematic, since `master` branch doesn't contain that file yet (you haven't done the merge), so it (XCode4) proposes to close that file, or to re-create it in the new working directory (the one for `master` branch).
- or you didn't committed that file yet, and Git, through XCode4, warns you about a file which might be lost when switching to `master`.
  Check your `git status` before switching branch: it should be clean.

Comment: My problem would fall to first one because I committed featured-branch and ready to merge. What options should I choose re-create or close that file ?

Comment: @art: I would recommend closing that file, then merging: you should see that file again. If not, this is a sure way to know the merge hasn't took place exactly as expected.

Comment: So I should doing merge in Terminal not through xcode interface right ?

Comment: @art: yes, in order to avoid all the XCode warning/messages.